# Open modal window after submitted and returned to page

Tags: php, jquery, popup, submit

I have function validate my form and after form submitted

```
else
            {
                $('.submit-button').val('Wait please...');
                $('.submit-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                return true;
            }
```

PHP redirect to main page

```
function wpcallback_get_target() {
    global $wpcallback_plugin_option;

    if($value = $callback_plugin_option['target'])
        return get_permalink($value);

    return get_site_url();
}
```

PHP get site url then how I can make thanks modal window opened?
I tried with .modal but can't find right place for it.

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Comment: have used ajax for for submission

Comment: @Mayank Vadiya, thx. Can you show example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

place `$('#myModal').modal('show');` in the bottom of you view file or you can add following code in head tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

to prevent model every time on page load, update your PHP file:

```
function wpcallback_get_target() {
    global $wpcallback_plugin_option;

    if($value = $callback_plugin_option['target'])
        return get_permalink($value);
    $url = get_site_url();
    return $url."?response=true";
}
```

in view file:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['response']) && $_GET['response'] == 'true'){ ?>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});

<?php } ?>
```

use Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myURL = window.location;
    var res = myURL.search("response=true");
    if(res > 0){
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks. I've already tried this. If I put it after else {...}  no result but if I put it outside function window appears on the main page every time it is loaded

Comment: you can send some query-string (see code above) to fix this problem

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why but you code hadn't show modal window but I studied window.location  and changed to $(document).ready(function(){
 if(window.location.href == "https://mysite.ru/?response=true"
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }   
});  Now it workd great. Thank you one more time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your `php`.

```
echo "<script>
         $(window).load(function(){
             $('#yourthanksmodel').modal('show');
         });
    </script>";
```

Comment: thanks. it doen't work inside the function but when I put it outside window appears on the main page. try to repair but no result, maybe you have ideas?

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot.